# 502 bad request when I reboot aws AMI redash

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-superset, redash

I have created a new server redash in aws Region us-west-2.
after a setup superset in server but error. I reboot server instance in aws and redash don't active.

> Bad Gateway: The proxy server received an invalid response from an
>   upstream server HTTP Error 502 - Bad Gateway

check error in cat /var/log/nginx/error.log I see:

> 2018/09/27 17:33:06 [error] 1192#1192: *16 recv() failed (104:
>   Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 210.245.121.234, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
>   upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "54.191.135.96" 2018/09/27
>   17:33:06 [error] 1192#1192: *16 connect() failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 210.245.121.234,
>   server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "54.191.135.96", referrer:
>   "http://54.191.135.96/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add your redash start command in your `/etc/init.d/` configuration ?

A simple installation on a Ec2 Server will not do that for you, you have to ask your ec2 to launch redash on startup process

There is multiple ways to do that, [AWS User data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) is one of them, try this out?

(If not, please provide us more information about your system and how you launch your redash)

Comment: @Rops42 do you know what exactly to add in /etc/init.d/ ?  It could really help.

Comment: Hi @Dawoodjee, please provide me your OS version and the command used to start Redash, i can't really help without it (sorry for my late answer)

Comment: So I used the AMI from the redash website after struggling with my own Ubuntu freezing. I think I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04 or 18.x. In the end I realized Rehash required larger RAM than was available on the micro EC2. It worked fine after increasing the swap to 2GB and rebooting.